# How do I get the trophy on the little island in batcavern?

Tags: batman-arkham-asylum

I have no idea how I can access this trophy:

http://img804.imageshack.us/img804/4541/senzatitolo1du.jpg

It's near the batcavern, but how do I get there?

Comment: You might want to re-upload to stack.imgur the image currently hosted on imageshack, as it's been transformed into an ad. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263771/ban-imageshack-images-because-they-are-reusing-old-urls-for-advertising

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is the one where you need to use the upgraded batclaw to pull down a wall in the cave, and through that path you can reach the "island" by some gliding and ziplines.

Comment: You are right..